Transcript/log ssh sessions with powershell
I have an powershell script which manage and perform ssh connections.
I would like to store the terminal history, or at least the ssh session, in a file.
I've already tried Transcript function, but it has some limitations and end up not storing all data, also, Tee-Object do not show the current line while in the ssh session.
There a alternative or know workaround to achieve this sessions "logging"?
I'm currently using the new "Windows Terminal" on Win11, with powershell 7.4.
In last scenario, there is an Unix alternative, to be used through wsl?

Two questions. What do you want to log, the history of your typed commands or also the output of those commands? Which system are you ssh-ing to, another powershell or a generic ssh server (e.g. unix)?

@mrq
I want to log everything i see on terminal, so would be both, commands and outputs.
I'm using powershell cause i have an "connection manager" script, but every single session would be a generic ssh server.
Giving more context, its a hundred different servers from different customers, and a single user to multiples employees, so i dont think a server side solution would be possible(in case it would be more than auxiliary functions inputted during the connection, or something in this way)
